# xml parsing using DOM parser

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I need to parse document using DOM parser in android. I was unable to print all the node values 
My Sample XML is:`

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
<news module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
<title data="Top Stories"/>
<section_type data="0"/>
<news_entry>
<title data="BSE Sensex breaches 19000, Nifty above 5800"/>
<url data="http://in.reuters.com/article/2012/10/04/sensex-above-19000-on-reform-hopes-         idINDEE89301O20121004"/>
<snippet data="| MUMBAI (Reuters) - The Nifty rose above 5800 points on Thursday,     joining the Sensex in breaching key psychological levels, after continued government reform  measures sparked hopes for continued action. Banks led gainers, with ICICI Bank (ICBK."/>
<source data="Reuters India"/>
<date data="3 hours ago"/>
<num_related data="145"/>
<cluster_url data="http://google.co.in/news/story?ncl=da6VmeBXmuquikM&hl=en"/>
</news_entry>
<news_entry>
<title data="Uncertainty over Kingfisher resuming operations tomorrow"/>
<url data="http://www.hindustantimes.com/India-news/NewDelhi/Uncertainty-over- Kingfisher-resuming-operations-tomorrow/Article1-939628.aspx"/>
<snippet data="Hopes of ailing Kingfisher Airlines resuming operations on Friday has faded with last ditch efforts by the management to persuade striking engineers and pilots to return to work failing to end the deadlock over the issue of non-payment of salaries for ..."/>
 <source data="Hindustan Times"/>
 <date data="1 hour ago"/>
 <num_related data="993"/>
 <cluster_url data="http://google.co.in/news/story?ncl=dzf460GzYKTOyxM&hl=en"/>
 </news_entry>
 </news>
 </xml_api_reply>`
```

and I am using following code to parse the xml

xmlactivity.java

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.google.co.in/ig/api?news&hl=en";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "news"; // parent node
//static final String KEY_ID = "news_entry";
static final String KEY_NAME = "title ";
static final String KEY_COST = "url ";
static final String KEY_DESC = "snippet";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        //map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        //map.put(KEY_COST,   parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
        //map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
/*  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });*/

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name});
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            //String name = ((TextView)       view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            //String cost = ((TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            //in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            //in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

and xmlParser.java

```
 public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child =   child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

}

please help me . what is the problem and suggestion
 thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I just advise you to use Sax or XmlPullParser instead of DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this code..


       public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
                String xml = null;

                try {
                    // defaultHttpClient

                    URLConnection conn = null; 
                    InputStream inputStream = null; 
                    URL urls = new URL(url); 
                    conn = urls.openConnection(); 
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); 
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn; 
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
                    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000); 
                    httpConn.connect(); 
                    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
                        inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream(); 
                    } 
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
                    StringWriter writer=new StringWriter(); 
                    String line=""; 
                    while ( null!=(line=in.readLine())){ 
                        writer.write(line);  
                    } 
                    xml =writer.toString();  

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return xml;
        }




        public Document getDomElement(String xml){
                Document doc = null;
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                try {

                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))); 
                    doc.normalize();
                    //InputSource is = new InputSource();
                   //     is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                       // doc = db.parse(is); 

                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    }

                    return doc;
            }


     public final String getElementValue(Node elem) { 
                Node child; 
                if (elem != null) { 
                    if (elem.hasChildNodes()) { 
                        for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child 
                                .getNextSibling()) { 
                            if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE) { 
                                return child.getTextContent(); 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                return ""; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://www.google.co.in/ig/api?news&hl=en";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "news"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "news_entry";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
    static final String KEY_COST = "url";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "snippet";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
             NamedNodeMap attributes = e.getAttributes();
            System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes.getLength());
             for (int a = 0; a < attributes.getLength(); a++) 
             {
                     Node theAttribute = attributes.item(a);
                     System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());
             }

             NodeList nl1=e.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ID);
             System.out.println("keyId"+nl1.getLength());
             for(int j=0;j<nl1.getLength();j++)
             {
                 Element e1 = (Element) nl1.item(j);

                 NodeList n = e1.getElementsByTagName(KEY_NAME);

                  for (int k = 0; k < n.getLength(); k++) {

                      Element e2 = (Element) n.item(k);
                //  System.out.println("node Title value"+e2.getNodeName());
                     NamedNodeMap attributes2 = e2.getAttributes();
                    // System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes2.getLength());
                     for (int a = 0; a < attributes2.getLength(); a++) 
                     {
                             Node theAttribute = attributes2.item(a);
                             System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());

                     }
                  }

                  NodeList n1 = e1.getElementsByTagName(KEY_COST);
                // System.out.println("title "+n.getLength());
                  for (int k = 0; k < n1.getLength(); k++) {

                      Element e2 = (Element) n1.item(k);
                //    System.out.println("node Url value");
                     NamedNodeMap attributes2 = e2.getAttributes();
                  //   System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes2.getLength());
                     for (int a = 0; a < attributes2.getLength(); a++) 
                     {
                             Node theAttribute = attributes2.item(a);
                             System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());

                     }}

                     NodeList n2 = e1.getElementsByTagName(KEY_DESC);
                    // System.out.println("title "+n.getLength());
                      for (int k = 0; k < n2.getLength(); k++) {

                          Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(k);
                    //    System.out.println("node snippet value"+e2.getNodeName());
                         NamedNodeMap attributes2 = e2.getAttributes();
                      //   System.out.println("attrlength"+attributes2.getLength());
                         for (int a = 0; a < attributes2.getLength(); a++) 
                         {
                                 Node theAttribute = attributes2.item(a);
                                 System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());

                         }
                      }  

             }



            menuItems.add(map);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i have edited my answer.It has complete parse code of url,title,snippet.

Comment: please remove space from declaration of keyname,keycost string in your code.