# Issue in XML parsing in Android

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Here is my XML.

```
 <results keywords="ipod" limit="25">
   <products count="30">
     <product merchant_price="179.99" 
       network_id="2" 
       name = "ipod" 
       retail_price="179.99" />
     <product merchant_price="189.99" 
       network_id="3"
       name="ipod16gb" 
       retail_price="189.99" />
   </products>
</results>
```

From this I need to fetch the product attributes alone. For that I have done this, I have a written a parser.

```
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML from the given URL
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");
// looping through all item nodes 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    Log.v("test",e.getAttribute("name"));
    }
```

But I am unable to get the value properly and getting
  `NullPointerException`
 Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132778/parsing-attribute-in-xml-with-dom-parser

Comment: please change loop for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
     Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
     NamedNodeMap attributes = e.getAttributes();
            for (int a = 0; a < attributes.getLength(); a++) 
       {
            Node theAttribute = attributes.item(a);
          System.out.println(theAttribute.getNodeName() + "=" + theAttribute.getNodeValue());
        }
```

Comment: Getting NUll pointer exception at                                   `code`     NamedNodeMap attributes = e.getAttributes();

Comment: can you tell me what you get by console printing e.getNodeName()

Comment: Now I am getting exception in this line if I try this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723450/xml-parsing-using-dom-parser/12724854#12724854

Comment: please check this link.I have parse attributes of xml nodes successfully.

Comment: I am doing almost similar thing. I am confusing between node, element. Trying to figure out the reason

Comment: what value youe get nl.getLength()

Comment: I have issue here `code` DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
   HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
   xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
   Log.v("print", xml);

Comment: Posted how I did it now. Thanks a lot @mukesh for helping me out.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1):

The loop is running 10 times which is more than the nodes present in your xml, that is why you are getting null pointer exception. Try `nl.length`(use a function which will return lenth of the list ) to get the number of elements in the list of elements you have made through `doc.getElementsByTagName("product");.`

Comment: I have just mentioned 2 elements for sample. There is a lot in real list

Comment: you are getting null pointer exception in e.getNodeName() and  e.getAttributes() that means e is null .....print nl.size() ..................................................................................

for (int i = 0; i < nl.size(); i++) {
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    Log.v("test",e.getAttribute("name"));
    }

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Xml parser. Corrected it with this while parsing.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```